# allow a point for textbox validation

Tags: c#

I need to allow only a period and a comma after a number. the point and the comma
They can not go alone as it is a field to validate. that it is only possible to enter a
number
and a comma.
This is the code that I have in the key press event.

```
CultureInfo cc = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar.ToString() == cc.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator || e.KeyChar.ToString() == cc.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator)
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = false;
}
else
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the keypress event, You want the textfields text changed event.

Regular expressions might help you here.